# match both field in EmbedDocuments

Tags: python, mongoengine

I need some help with mongoengine filtering please. What I am trying to do is to filter 2 fields in embed documents. I want both to match within the same document but I cannot figure out how to contain it that way.

sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "active" : true,
    "booking" : [ 
        {
            "date" : 1,
            "status" : true
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "active" : true,
    "booking" : [ 
        {
            "date" : 1,
            "status" : false
        },
        {
            "date" : 2,
            "status" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query `day=1 & status=true` and get only #1 as result. However this query would return both #1 and #2 as both day and status can exist across documents.

```
docs.objects.filter(
    Q(active=True) & Q(booking__date=1) & Q(booking__status=True))
```

I tried a few different things but they give result way farther from what I expecting. Such as these which return empty.

```
match = {"$match": {
    "booking.date": 1,
    "booking.status": True
}}
objects = docs.objects.aggregate(match)
```

or

```
match = {"$match": {
                "$and": [
                    {
                        "booking.date": 1,
                        "booking.status": True
                    }
                ]
            }}
```

Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is:

```py
class Booking(EmbeddedDocument):
    date = IntField()
    status = BooleanField(default=True)

class Account(Document):
    active = BooleanField(default=True)
    booking = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Booking)

Account.objects(active=True, booking=Booking(date=1, status=True))
```

The key point is I use whole `EmbeddedDocument` as a matching criteria. Also `Q(active=True) & Q(booking__date=1) & Q(booking__status=True)` is completely equivalent to `active=True, booking__date=1, booking__status=True`